# Trouble with 8bit ALU overflow and carryout using VHDL

Tags: logic, vhdl, hardware, fpga

I have been trying to design an 8 bit ALU, but i had trouble with overflow and Cout. I spent hours trying to do it but with no correct result, I hope that someone explain how to correct it. thanks a lot.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity ALU_8_bit is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           CTRL : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           Y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              OFL: out STD_LOGIC;
              COUT: out STD_LOGIC
              );
end ALU_8_bit;



architecture Behavioral of ALU_8_bit is

signal result: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin

process(A,B,CTRL) begin
    if (CTRL ="000") then
        result <= A; 
    elsif (CTRL = "001") then
        result <= A + B; 
    elsif (CTRL = "010") then
        result <= A - B;
    elsif (CTRL = "011") then
        result <= NOT A + 1;
    elsif (CTRL = "100") then
        result <= NOT A; 
    elsif (CTRL = "101") then
        result <= A AND B;
    elsif (CTRL = "110") then 
        result <= A OR B;  
    else --(CTRL = "111") then
        result <= A XOR B;
    end if;
end process;

Y <= result;

--process (A,B,result,cout)
--begin
--  if  ((A(3) = '1') and (B(3) ='1') and (result(3) = '0')) then Cout <= '1';
--  elsif ((A(3) = '1') and (B(3) = '0') and (result(3) = '0')) then Cout <= '1';
--  elsif ((A(3) = '0') and (B(3) = '1') and (result(3) = '0')) then Cout <= '1';
--  else Cout <= '0';
--  end if;
--end process;

process(result,CTRL)
begin 
    if (CTRL = "001") then
        --Y <= result;
        COUT <=  A(3) and B(3); --result(3);
        OFL <= result(3) xor (B(2) and A(2));
    else 
        OFL <= '0';
        COUT <= '0';
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I think the trick you're looking for is to make "result" one bit wider than the inputs, to hold the carry. Then you need to extend the inputs by 1 bit before adding them...

Comment: Per Brian's comment `COUT` is assigned `result(4)`. Also note the `OFL` case needs to be specified for both add and subtract (and correctly) see [Calculating Overflow Flag: Method 1](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) (read the whole thing). You'd continue to use `A(3)`, `B(3)` and `result(3)` bits). Note that in reality A - B is A + not B + 1, where the + 1 represents the carry in. You're counting on synthesis to make only one ALU. If you had carry in you could use Method 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if youu want to obtain the Cout and the overflow, it is preferable to do create the variable **result** with one bit more:

signal result: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

And depending on the operation you can compare the required bits to know if it carryes out or overflows.

By the way, it is a 4-bit ALU, not 8